# mass change to all queries in a DB

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database with many year-specific table names (not my design).  I want to copy the DB to a new DB  and update all tables to have the same name but updated from "xxx_2007" to "xxx_2008", and have all queries that reference "2007" updated to  reference "2008" instead.  These references might be in table names or may be selection criteria in the query.

The approach I'm using now is to open each query, copy the SQL to notepad, replace "2007" with "2008", then copy it back to the SQL view of the query.  It's workable, but tedious.

Any suggestions on programmatic way to update everything?

Comment: My suggestion: Don't just find a way to "hack" a bad 2007-specific design into a bad 2008-specific design. Fix it properly so you don't have to "hack" it again the next time.

Comment: @Gord - I agree, but this is (or should be) a one-time missue to rerspond to an audit of 2007 and 2008 data, and I hope to never use the system again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Gord said.

But if you really need a quick hack to make it work *right now*, you can loop the QueryDefs collection:

```
Dim DB As Database
Dim QD As QueryDef
Dim S As String

Set DB = CurrentDb
For Each QD In DB.QueryDefs
    S = QD.SQL
    If InStr(S, "2007") > 0 Then
        S = Replace(S, "2007", "2008")
        QD.SQL = S
    End If
Next QD
```

Similar with `TableDefs` for table names, here you would replace `TD.Name`

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend what Gord stated. If not, simply use Rick Fisher's Find and Replace http://www.rickworld.com/products.html.